# Jira comments and customfield rendering in vm file

Tags: html, jira, velocity, jira-plugin

I need some help with my Search-Request-View Plugin, I can render most of the issue informations. However not the comments and the customfield. Normaly I would make a foreach and render each comments but in $issue.comments is nothing so I thought there must be another way to render it.

By the way I want to render my Issues on a Html Site.

For example I show you how I rendered my attachments in my issue:

```
##Attachments
    #if(!$!issue.attachments.empty)
        #foreach($attachment in $!issue.attachments)
            #set($attachmentUrl = "${requestContext.baseUrl}/secure/attachment/${attachment.id}/${urlcodec.encode($attachment.filename)}")
            <div class="Bild">
                <img src="$attachmentUrl">
                <p>$urlcodec.encode($attachment.filename)</p>
            </div>
        #end
    #end
```

But this way the comments doesn't work.

And the costumFields I don't know how to render them, so I would appreciate your help, Thanks

Or does anyone know the variables I have to use or where I can find them?
(Like **$issue.attachments** for the attachments or **$issue.priorityObject.nameTranslation** for the priority)
I mostly find them randomly in the web and try out how they work but I couldn't find a documentation or something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it now, for others with the same problem here is my solution:

```
issueParams.put("comments", ComponentAccessor.getCommentManager().getComments(issue));
issueParams.put("links", ComponentAccessor.getIssueLinkManager().getOutwardLinks(issue.getId()));
```

Comments and Links do work this way and customFields I#m trying now but I think it should work this way too